# how i calculate cosine similarity by using jama

Tags: java, tf-idf, svd, cosine-similarity, lsa

could anyone help me with detecting the problem? I need to calculate the similarity between the query and a collection of documents, and I've been used the program : https://github.com/aliabbasrizvi/LatentSemanticIndexing][1]. In this program, the similarity was calculated by "dot product" and I change it to "cosine similarity" but I got a high similarity score while I should get it between 0 and 1.
can anyone tell me what is the wrong? is TF_IDF have any effect? or something else?

those results that I got it"

1. Document: b4, Relevance score: 2.185808108221954
2. Document: h286, Relevance score: 1.1350011283882473E-16

This is the code I was used it for similarity"

```
public double getVectorModulus(Matrix matrix) {                 
            double dotProduct = 0.0;
            double magnitude1 = 0.0;
            double magnitude2 = 0.0;
            double cosineSimilarity = 0.0;
            double a=0.0, b=0.0;
            int i = 0,j = 0;
              for ( i = 0; i < matrix.getRowDimension(); i++)
                { a=matrix.get(i, 0);
                  b= matrix.get(i, 0);
                   dotProduct += (a*b);  //a.b
                    magnitude1+=Math.pow(a, 2); //a^2
                    magnitude2+=Math.pow(b, 2); //b^2
                }
            magnitude1+=Math.sqrt(magnitude1); //   sqrt(a^2)
            magnitude2+=Math.sqrt(magnitude2); //   sqrt(b^2)
            if(magnitude1 !=0.0 | magnitude2 !=0.0)
                cosineSimilarity = dotProduct / (magnitude1 *magnitude2);    
    return cosineSimilarity;
    }
```

Comment: Why are a and b the same number? In both cases you use matrix.get(i, 0);

Comment: @RetteMich because  matrix.get(i,0) use to store the query and perform operations on it and after that the same matrix.get(i,0) use to store documents and also perform the same operations on it.